# How can I get Update Manager to Check & Notify for DAILY updates

Tags: update-manager

In Software Sources, I have Update Manager set to check for updates DAILY. I also selected the setting to Notify but not to download or install updates.

Considering my settings, Why do I not receive Daily notifications when updates are available?

For example, Google Chrome PPA released a SECURITY update Tuesday. Yet as I write this my Update Manager has not alerted me that there is an update available for my Google Chrome PPA. From past experience I know that if I manually run Update Manager the Chrome PPA update will be available.

How do I get Update Manager to CHECK and NOTIFY for updates DAILY? I do not want to have to manually run Update Manager on a daily basis to see if there are updates available.

This happens on both Lucid and Natty.

In Startup Applications - Update Notifier is enabled.

Comment: 10.04 and 11.04 (desktop and laptop)

Comment: I think I got it! gconf-editor: apps/update-notifier/regular_auto_launch_interval. Mine was set to 7. I changed it to zero (0). THANK YOU for your help fossfreedom (or whoever posted that pic about checking gconf-editor's auto_launch setting. This is what ultimately led to me solving this. thank you so much!

Comment: indeed - changed the piccy.

Answer (score 1):

Using gconf-editor check that the Auto-Launch checkbox as shown in this image is ticked.

(As found by Nick) - check also that the option (highlighted) "regular_auto_launch_interval" is set to zero.

[image]

Comment: If I change my settings to "Install Security Updates without confirmation" will this cause the Update Manager to CHECK & INSTALL for updates DAILY? Update Notifier is activated on my box. All I want is for the Update Manager to do what the settings say: check daily for updates and if update/s are available notify me. Why doesn't it do this?

Comment: auto_launch is ticked on my box. I know Update Manager works because I do get notifications about updates. It's just that the notifications are not timely. For example, if I wait long enough (maybe a week), Update Manager will notify me about the Google Chrome PPA update. I can post an image of my gconf-editor update-notifier settings if this will help. But I don't know how to paste/post the image here as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

In dash type "software sources" and return to select it. The parameter you want is on the Updates tab "Automatically check for updates".