# update-manager not starting automatically

Tags: 11.10, update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make Update Manager stop opening automatically?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85226/how-do-i-make-update-manager-stop-opening-automatically)

On my 11.10 installation, which I installed fresh on a new computer about a month ago, update-manager is not popping up automatically when new upgrades are available.

I have set the options in "Software Sources" to check daily for updates, and to "display immediately" when new security or regular updates are available.

I checked the answer from [How can I get Update Manager to Check & Notify for DAILY updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53129/how-can-i-get-update-manager-to-check-notify-for-daily-updates), but this didn't solve the problem for me.

Update-notifier is installed on my system, but does not run. Do I have to put that myself into the Startup applications?