# How do I have my Ubuntu system automatically update?

Tags: updates

I have not been getting updates. Is there somewhere I can go to receive regular updates when they are available? I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get Update Manager to Check & Notify for DAILY updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53129/how-can-i-get-update-manager-to-check-notify-for-daily-updates/90689#90689)

Comment: @georgesteiner you can accept the answer by clicking the tick mark next to the answer and make it green.

Answer (score 3):

Go to

System Settings > Software and Updates > Updates

Set

- **Automatically check for updates** to `daily`
- Set `display immediately` for both **Security and Other Updates**

You can always update manually by running the following commands in the terminal, one after the other

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: @georgesteiner please accept the answer